# Shape/graph sizes as zoom level changes

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I draw a square that is 10cm(h) x 10cm(w) and my zoom is 100%, why does the shape size change if I zoom to say 130% where I get values of 10cm(h) x 9.98(w). If I use the zoom scroll the size changes for every zoom level that is not rounded to 100 (e.g. 200%, 300% and 400%) are fine.

Comment: That's simply not the purpose of Excel, of course you can attempt to do it, but not guaranteed to work correctly.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I don't understand you comments, what is not the purpose of the Excel? Drawing a square?

Answer (score 0):

I have no references for this and can only speak from a programmers point of view. I think you could rightly call what you have found a bug, and if you google it you'll probably find that someone has noted it somewhere already.

I would guess its a necessary evil for Excel and won't be changing anytime soon. Computers, displays and printers don't work in cm's but rather in pixels and dots. MS Word for instance doesn't have this problem because the document from the ground up is designed to be printed. Shapes and letters are primarily defined by the size they will be when printed. The dots per inch of your printer will ultimately determine if e.g. a 300 pixel line prints out as 2.54cm (300dpi) or 1.27 cmm (600 dpi). Word remembers your intention and back calculates to the number of pixels to display/dots to print all the time. In contrast MS Excel was designed to display lots of cells on screens in pixels. Column widths are define in pixels (default 80 pixels). If you screenshot Excel and paste it into MS Paint, you can count the width of the cell is actually 80 pixels (unless Windows is doing some display scaling for you). If you print the spreadsheet, scaling is done only when you set the print area and set up the page scaling. Fundamentally, when you size a shape to be equal to the width of one column, Excel probably only stores the pixel width. To make it more comprehensible to the user, it scales this to cm based on the current page/printer/screen zoom configuration. I would have preferred they rather let you specify the size in pixels (like they do with column widths) or at least give you the option to.

Answer (score 0):

Excel measures in something I've seen referred to as "thwips" and while I can't verify that term in anything I know directly from MS, the real point is there are 1800+ of them per inch. This is akin to the point `Mobus` makes, but "pixels" kind of contectualizes it as a pic or a monitor and it's really something a little different:  not different in essential meaning, just not to carry any extra contextual meaning the usual uses of "pixel" carry.

So your box would really be some number like 146 x 143. 3 parts in over 1800, not necesssarily discernible on your monitor, looks square. Then you ask Excel to report the sizes in centimeters or inches. And 3 parts in over 1800 gives Excel a "cm" size to report as 7.69x7.69 WHEN ROUNDED TO THE TWO DECIMAL PLACES. Might really be more like 7.692305...x7.688921... but it's reporting to two decimal places so the 7.69x7.69 and you accept what you see (what choice do you have without something more in depth?) as a perfect square.

Then you enlarge the cell. And now get measurements like 10.00x9.98. That's because the pre-rounded values are now different enough for the post-rounded values to show a small difference. Hence your finding the original box was NOT in fact perfectly square.

How can that help you? Well, you could craft such things LARGE SCALE, refining them to apparent perfection, then scale them down. The rounding aspect should (should) lessen in importance as one scales down. Unfortunately, it will be a threshhold thing and any given scale-down could actually create (force) a mismatch where one didn't exist at the larger scale (and will cease to exist, then maybe appear again, and so on, if you keep scaling down as the nearness to mattering waxes and wanes). Worse, depending on how that scaling is done, the physical process of scaling might introduce mismatching:  if the measurement you have available is, say, 9.71 scaling down to 50% is impossible to actually achieve as Excel would not accept 4.855, making you pick 4.85 or 4.86.

The biggest source of difference as you try to square the cell is Excel is using centimeters, say, for the row height, but "CHARACTERS" of the currently applied font for width and how would you EVER match those exactly? Not even luck will help that.

The trick would be to switch to "Page Layout" view to match the height and width. Page Layout view uses the same measurement system for height AND width, so you get the exact same height and width with no conversion errors. 1.2cm high by 1.2cm wide is really that. If one is not acceptable to Excel and rounded from your entry, the other will be too, and in the exact same way. So you enter 1.199964cm for each and it makes one 1.2cm, it will make the other 1.2cm. Not getting your exact desired size might vex you, but you WILL have the square you desired. And scaling up or down from that should stay perfect.

Then shift back to the view you prefer, Normal view probably, and never re-size either measurement without going back to Page Layout for the changes. Then return to your desired View.

Unfortunately, how any given monitor physically forms pixels will govern how your (truly) perfect box displays. If a given monitor creates a pixel that is 1cm wide (obviously not a real number, just for making the point here) but 0.9925412cm tall, it will never display your perfect square as a perfect square. And some other user's monitor is slightly different so even if you edit to display as a perfect square on that first one, you'll be off on the second. And even if they are all the same, real manufacturing has plus-or-minus tolerances that mean two monitors from the same production line WILL differ. Not to mention that the actual temperatures in the operating monitors will make two monitors that were somehow perfectly the same different in usage, moment to moment.

What I'm saying is... you want a technically perfect square? The Page Layout thing will let you achieve that. But it will never be perfect in actual use, even on your own machine (a single machine at two different times IS the last example I used, that of two somehow perfectly the same monitors). So does the difference you noticed in reported values actually SHOW when looking at the square? If no, then what is the need for more perfect crafting? If "maybe", then use the Page Layout approach and know they are perfect regardless of how you do or do not see non-squareness. But just don't waste your time seeking technical perfection for its own sake when the real world will throw it off from perfect in actual use no matter that you do. Go home earlier and look at some nice art online, or pet the dog longer, or sweep the back porch tonight instead. Something better for your life than a perfection you can't have anyway.